# Moshi JSON Parsing - Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at path

Tags: android, jsonparser, moshi

I have the following JSON to parse. I am using moshi to parse it but i am getting the error which says,
"**Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at path $.properties.band[0].properties.bandwidth[0]**"

```
 {
  "properties": {
   "band": [
   {
    "baseFrequency": 123,
    "properties": {
      "channel": {
        "minChannel": 1,
        "maxChannel": 2,
        "step": 1
      },
      "power": {
        "minPower": -1,
        "maxPower": 0,
        "step": 1
      },
      "bandwidth": [
        20,
        40
      ]
    }
  }
 ]}
}
```

In my class file i have defined bandwidth as List.
I have tried to change it into others too, but i always get error.

My Properties file content:

```
public class Properties {
   @Json(name = "channel")
   private Channel channel;
   @Json(name = "power")
   private Power power;
   @Json(name = "bandwidth")
   private List<Integer> bandwidth = null;
}
```

Can you please point me out on the right direction?

Comment: Your pojo class looks like perfect.  Check what response coming.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya My response string is exactly the one that i have pasted. It looks okay.